# Как делаются подобные кнопки ?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В яндексе вбил ключевое слово "кафе апельсин семеновская"

[ТЫК](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=кафе%20апельсин%20семеновская&clid=1882610&lr=213)

Хотел бы узнать, как можно сделать подобную кнопку, как и в примере первого сайта "Забронировать столик" ?

Answer (score 1):

[Вот так](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/interactive-answers/buttons-description.xml)